# How do I get a child attribute from a e.currentTarget.value JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an attribute from the child of the the `currentTarget`. I have tried this,
(`e.currentTarget.child.attr("data-english"`)

I have googled it and have had no luck finding anything useful, maybe its me being new with code I might be looking up the wrong thing.

Here is the HTML

```
 < select class="form-control" id="select_fundFamily"     name="select_fundFamily" autocomplete="off" >
  < option value="stuff" data-english="english" data-family-locallang="model" >
```

At the moment in JQuery, the `e.currentTarget.value;` is showing the select element.

Can someone please kindly advise me in what path to take to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

For the value of the selected option in a select, you can use

```
$(e.currentTarget).find(':selected').attr("data-english");
```

Run the snippet below to see it work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function(e){
         var eng = $(e.currentTarget).find(':selected').attr("data-english");
        $('body').append(eng);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_fundFamily"> 
    <option selected disabled>Select something</option>
    <option value="stuff1" data-english="english1" >1</option>
    <option value="stuff2" data-english="english2" >2</option>
    <option value="stuff3" data-english="english3" >3</option>
    <option value="stuff4" data-english="english4" >4</option>
    <option value="stuff5" data-english="english5" >5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try to determine the selected option's attribute. A simple solution is:

```
var dataEnglish = $('#select_fundFamily option:selected').attr('data-english'); // dataEnglish = english
```

Comment: A more elegant way - in case you want to determine that when the 'change' event occurs -  you can also have it done like: $('#select_fundFamily').on('change', function (e) {
        var option = $("option:selected", this);

        console.log(option.attr('data-english')); // english
    });

Answer (score 1):

currentTarget will respond any element that event listener triggered the event. In your case, i think you want to use e.target to target the right element.

```
$("select#select_fundFamily").on('click','option', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).attr('data-english'); // you can use $(this) instead
    //something else
});
```